# ExpandableListView - detect when all groups are collapsed

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` and perform some actions when a group is expanded:

```
    @Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    p = (RelativeLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.pers);
    p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ExpandableListView elw = (ExpandableListView) activity
            .findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
        elw.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
    }
    lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

}
```

I need to set the `RelativeLayout` visible when ALL groups are collapsed (or when no group is expanded). How can I detect that all groups are currently collapsed?

Answer (score 1):

You have two equivalent options:

1. Implement `ExpandableListAdapter` methods: `onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition)` and `onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)` of your `ExandableListView`'s adapter.
2. Add custom `OnGroupCollapseListener` and `OnGroupExpandListener` and attach them to the expandable list view via `setOnGroupCollapseListener()` and `setOnGroupExpandListener()` respectively.

In both of these options what you basically want to do is to track what groups are currently expanded. A good way would be to keep them as a `Set<Integer>`. When a group is collapsed you remove its ID from this set. Similarly when a group is expanded you add its ID to this set. After each add/remove you check the size of the set. If it's empty then all groups are collapsed. If not - some group is expanded.

As far as I know, there is not direct method of finding out which groups are expanded/collapsed.

Comment: Actually, I think you can check whether or not a group is expanded using `isGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)` which is called on the ExpandableListView. But I agree, you should implement a listener and track the open groups in a list rather on iterating through the entire list and checking if each group is expanded/collapsed.

Comment: of course, I know, but you have to iterate over all the IDs every time, which for me is an overkill :)